# Firebase vs Node.js server

Tags: node.js, firebase, frontend, backend

I need to build quickly a client app for web, IOS & Android. The app should handle authentication (login, signup & forgot password) and show the user his saved data, some sort of editable data table, thats all.

I read about Firebase and I've been wondering... Do I need to create a node.js server side or can I count on Google's Firebase cause there isn't much complexity (never used firebase)?

thnx

Comment: NodeJS and ExpressJs are the best and easy way to implement , even firebase uses nodejs internal system , yes you can learn firebase if you want .

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."